# Matlab: How to extract specific cells from a 3D array using list of indices?

Tags: matlab

I have a source matrix A(m,n) for which I used "find" and now I have a list of desired indices [y,x].

I also have a 3D matrix with dimensions B(m,n,3).

I want to extract all the elements in B using the result from find.

So if find yields 4 pairs of results, I would like to have a 4x3 matrix with the contents of the Z dimension of B for the resulting indices.

I tried many things but keep failing:

```
A = rand(480,640);
[y,x] = find(A < 0.5);
o = B(y,x,:);

Requested 39024x39024x3 (34.0GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference.
```

I am clearly doing something wrong since B has dimensions (640,640,3).

Answer (score 0):

With the way you are trying to index, matlab tries to index B with every combination of the elements in y and x resulting in a massive matrix. I've implemented a `for loop` to do what I think you are asking.

I would also note that in order to index across `B` the first two dimensions need to be the same size as `A`, Otherwise you will not be able to index `B` past the maximum row or column index in `A`.

```matlab
A = rand(480,640);
B = rand(480,640,3);
[x,y] = find(A < 0.5);

o = zeros(size(x,1),1,3); % x and y are the same length so it doesn't matter
for i = 1:size(x,1)
    o(i,1,:)= B(x(i),y(i),:);
end
o = reshape(o,size(x,1),3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) B to a 2D matrix of size `[m*n , 3]` then use logical indexing to extract elements:

```
C = reshape(B, [], 3);
o = C(A<0.5, :);
```